# conda create -n anaconda won't install full anaconda packages

Tags: python, anaconda

I'd like to create a python3.6 env with default anaconda packages. The manual and many online resources say the command is `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda`. On other computers that works, but on one particular computer it only installs very few packages. I can't figure out why. I've checked `$HOME/anaconda2/env` and there's nothing in there.
(ubuntu 16.04, installed from anaconda, not miniconda)

```
$ conda update anaconda
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

$ conda update conda
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
$conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/memo/anaconda2/envs/py36

  added / updated specs: 
    - anaconda
    - python=3.6


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    anaconda:        custom-py36hbbc8b67_0            
    ca-certificates: 2018.10.15-ha4d7672_0 conda-forge
    certifi:         2018.10.15-py36_1000  conda-forge
    libffi:          3.2.1-hfc679d8_5      conda-forge
    libgcc-ng:       7.2.0-hdf63c60_3      conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng:    7.2.0-hdf63c60_3      conda-forge
    ncurses:         6.1-hfc679d8_1        conda-forge
    openssl:         1.0.2p-h470a237_1     conda-forge
    pip:             18.1-py36_1000        conda-forge
    python:          3.6.6-h5001a0f_3      conda-forge
    readline:        7.0-haf1bffa_1        conda-forge
    setuptools:      40.5.0-py36_0         conda-forge
    sqlite:          3.25.3-hb1c47c0_0     conda-forge
    tk:              8.6.8-ha92aebf_0      conda-forge
    wheel:           0.32.2-py36_0         conda-forge
    xz:              5.2.4-h470a237_1      conda-forge
    zlib:            1.2.11-h470a237_3     conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? n



$ conda list

# packages in environment at /home/memo/anaconda2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py27h08a7f0c_0  
absl-py                   0.6.1                     <pip>
absl-py                   0.5.0                     <pip>
alabaster                 0.7.10           py27he5a193a_0  
anaconda                  custom           py27h4a00acb_0  
anaconda-client           1.6.9                    py27_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.8.4                    py27_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2            py27h236b58a_0  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py27_0  
astor                     0.7.1                     <pip>
astroid                   1.6.1                    py27_0  
astropy                   2.0.3            py27h14c3975_0  
attrs                     17.4.0                   py27_0  
audioread                 2.1.4                    py27_1    conda-forge
babel                     2.5.3                    py27_0  
backports                 1.0              py27h63c9359_1  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.4              py27he8db605_1  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0            py27h5bc021e_2  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                 <pip>
backports_abc             0.5              py27h7b3c97b_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py27h3f86ba9_1  
bibtexparser              1.0.1                     <pip>
bitarray                  0.8.1            py27h14c3975_1  
bkcharts                  0.2              py27h241ae91_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
blaze                     0.11.3           py27h5f341da_0  
bleach                    1.5.0                     <pip>
bleach                    2.1.2                    py27_0  
blosc                     1.14.4               hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
bokeh                     0.12.13          py27h5233db4_0  
boost                     1.59.0                   py27_0    menpo
boto                      2.48.0           py27h9556ac2_1  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py27h21b16a3_0  
bzip2                     1.0.6                h9a117a8_4  
ca-certificates           2018.10.15           ha4d7672_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.14.6                        4    conda-forge
cdecimal                  2.3              py27h14c3975_3  
certifi                   2018.10.15            py27_1000    conda-forge
cffi                      1.11.4           py27h9745a5d_0  
cgal-bindings             1.2                       <pip>
chardet                   3.0.4            py27hfa10054_1  
click                     6.7              py27h4225b90_0  
cloudpickle               0.5.2                    py27_1  
clyent                    1.2.2            py27h7276e6c_1  
colorama                  0.3.9            py27h5cde069_0  
conda                     4.5.11                py27_1000    conda-forge
conda-build               3.4.1                    py27_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1  
conda-verify              2.0.0            py27hf052a9d_0  
configparser              3.5.0            py27h5117587_0  
contextlib2               0.5.5            py27hbf4c468_0  
cryptography              2.3.1            py27hdffb7b8_0    conda-forge
cryptography-vectors      2.3.1                 py27_1000    conda-forge
curl                      7.61.0               h93b3f91_2    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0           py27hc7354d3_0  
cython                    0.27.3           py27hc56b35e_0  
cytoolz                   0.9.0            py27h14c3975_0  
dask                      0.16.1                   py27_0  
dask-core                 0.16.1                   py27_0  
datashape                 0.5.4            py27hf507385_0  
dbus                      1.13.0               h3a4f0e9_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.3.0                     <pip>
decorator                 4.2.1                    py27_0  
distributed               1.20.2                   py27_0  
dlib                      19.16.0                   <pip>
dlib                      19.4                     py27_0    menpo
docopt                    0.6.2                     <pip>
docutils                  0.14             py27hae222c1_0  
dominate                  2.3.4                     <pip>
dxfwrite                  1.2.1                     <pip>
entrypoints               0.2.3            py27h502b47d_2  
enum34                    1.1.6            py27h99a27e9_1  
enum34                    1.1.6                     <pip>
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py27h75840f5_0  
expat                     2.2.5                he0dffb1_0  
fastcache                 1.0.2            py27h14c3975_2  
ffmpeg                    3.1.3                         0    menpo
filelock                  2.0.13           py27h61a9c69_0  
flask                     0.12.2           py27h6d5c1cd_0  
flask-cors                3.0.3            py27h1a8a27f_0  
flickr-api                0.6.1                     <pip>
fontconfig                2.12.1                        4    conda-forge
freetype                  2.7                           1    conda-forge
funcsigs                  1.0.2                     <pip>
funcsigs                  1.0.2            py27h83f16ab_0  
functools32               3.2.3.2          py27h4ead58f_1  
future                    0.17.1                   py27_0    anaconda
futures                   3.2.0            py27h7b459c0_0  
futures                   3.2.0                     <pip>
gast                      0.2.0                     <pip>
geomstats                 1.5                       <pip>
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h5e8e0c9_1    conda-forge
gevent                    1.2.2            py27h475ea6a_0  
glib                      2.51.4                        0    conda-forge
glob2                     0.6              py27hcea9cbd_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py27h4cf3fa8_2  
graphite2                 1.3.10               hf63cedd_1  
greenlet                  0.4.12           py27hac09c53_0  
grin                      1.2.1                    py27_4  
grpcio                    1.15.0                    <pip>
grpcio                    1.16.0                    <pip>
gst-plugins-base          1.8.0                         0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.8.0                         1    conda-forge
h5py                      2.8.0                     <pip>
h5py                      2.8.0            py27hb794570_1    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  1.4.3                         0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.2               hc401514_1    conda-forge
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py27_2  
html5lib                  0.9999999                 <pip>
html5lib                  1.0.1            py27h5233db4_0  
httplib2                  0.11.3                    <pip>
icu                       58.2                 hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.6              py27h5722d68_1  
idna                      2.7                       <pip>
imageio                   2.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
imagesize                 0.7.1            py27hd17bf80_0  
imutils                   0.5.1                     <pip>
intel-openmp              2018.0.0             hc7b2577_8  
ipaddress                 1.0.19                   py27_0  
ipykernel                 4.8.0                    py27_0  
ipython                   5.4.1                    py27_2  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py27h89fb69b_0  
ipywidgets                7.1.1                    py27_0  
isort                     4.2.15           py27hcfa4749_0  
itsdangerous              0.24             py27hb8295c1_1  
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0  
jdcal                     1.3              py27h2cc5433_0  
jedi                      0.11.1                   py27_0  
jinja2                    2.10             py27h4114e70_0  
joblib                    0.12.5                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                   h470a237_1    conda-forge
jsonschema                2.6.0            py27h7ed5aa4_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py27_4  
jupyter_client            5.2.2                    py27_0  
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py27hc6bee7e_1  
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py27h345911c_0  
jupyterlab                0.31.5                   py27_0  
jupyterlab_launcher       0.10.2                   py27_0  
Keras                     2.2.2                     <pip>
Keras-Applications        1.0.6                     <pip>
Keras-Preprocessing       1.0.5                     <pip>
kiwisolver                1.0.1                    py27_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.14.6                        0    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py27h682c727_0  
libcurl                   7.61.1               heec0ca6_0  
libedit                   3.1.20170329         haf1bffa_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc                    7.2.0                h69d50b8_2    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1    anaconda
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1  
libgfortran-ng            7.2.0                h9f7466a_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 h470a237_3    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.2.20               h9ac9557_7  
libopus                   1.2.1                hb9ed12e_0  
libpng                    1.6.34               hb9fc6fc_0  
librosa                   0.6.2                      py_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.15               hf101ebd_0  
libssh2                   1.8.0                h5b517e9_2    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1    anaconda
libtiff                   4.0.7                         1    conda-forge
libtool                   2.4.6                h544aabb_3  
libuuid                   2.32.1               h470a237_2    conda-forge
libvpx                    1.6.1                h888fd40_0  
libxcb                    1.12                 hcd93eb1_4  
libxml2                   2.9.8                h422b904_5    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.32               h88dbc4e_2    conda-forge
linecache2                1.0.0                    py27_0    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.23.0                   py27_1    conda-forge
locket                    0.2.0            py27h73929a2_1  
lws                       1.2                       <pip>
lxml                      4.1.1            py27hdd00cef_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2  
Markdown                  3.0.1                     <pip>
markupsafe                1.0              py27h97b2822_1  
matplotlib                2.1.0                    py27_0    conda-forge
mccabe                    0.6.1            py27h0e7c7be_1  
mido                      1.2.9                     <pip>
mistune                   0.8.3                    py27_0  
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1  
mkl-service               1.1.2            py27hb2d42c5_4  
mkl_fft                   1.0.5                    py27_0    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.0.1                    py27_0    conda-forge
mock                      2.0.0                     <pip>
moviepy                   0.2.3.5                   <pip>
mpc                       1.0.3                hec55b23_5  
mpfr                      3.1.5                h11a74b3_2  
mpmath                    1.0.0            py27h9669132_2  
msgpack-python            0.5.1            py27h6bb024c_0  
multipledispatch          0.4.9            py27h9b5f95a_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.0                    py27_0  
nbconvert                 5.3.1            py27he041f76_0  
nbformat                  4.4.0            py27hed7f2b2_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  hfc679d8_1    conda-forge
networkx                  2.1                      py27_0  
ninja                     1.8.2                h2d50403_1    conda-forge
nltk                      3.2.5            py27hec5f4de_0  
nose                      1.3.7            py27heec2199_2  
notebook                  5.4.0                    py27_0  
numba                     0.38.1                   py27_0    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.6.6                    py27_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.15.4                    <pip>
numpy                     1.15.3           py27h1d66e8a_0  
numpy                     1.14.5                    <pip>
numpy-base                1.15.3           py27h81de0dd_0  
numpy-stl                 2.7.0                     <pip>
numpydoc                  0.7.0            py27h9647a75_0  
oauth2                    1.9.0.post1               <pip>
odo                       0.5.1            py27h9170de3_0  
olefile                   0.45.1                   py27_0  
openblas                  0.2.20                        8    conda-forge
opencv-contrib-python     3.4.3.18                  <pip>
opencv-python             3.4.3.18                  <pip>
openpyxl                  2.4.10                   py27_0  
openssl                   1.0.2p               h470a237_1    conda-forge
packaging                 16.8             py27h5e07c7c_1  
pandas                    0.23.0           py27h637b7d7_0  
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hea2e7c5_1  
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py27h428e1e5_1  
pango                     1.40.4                        0    conda-forge
parso                     0.1.1            py27h718acc2_0  
partd                     0.3.8            py27h4e55004_0  
patchelf                  0.9                  hf79760b_2  
path.py                   10.5             py27hefe4bee_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.0            py27h6e9d198_0  
patsy                     0.5.0                    py27_0  
pbr                       5.1.0                     <pip>
pbr                       4.2.0                     <pip>
pcre                      8.39                          1  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py27_0  
pexpect                   4.3.1                    py27_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4            py27h09770e1_0  
Pillow                    5.3.0                     <pip>
Pillow                    5.2.0                     <pip>
pillow                    4.3.0                    py27_1    conda-forge
pip                       9.0.1            py27ha730c48_4  
pixman                    0.34.0               h470a237_3    conda-forge
pkginfo                   1.4.1            py27hee1a9ad_1  
pluggy                    0.6.0            py27h1f4f128_0  
ply                       3.10             py27hd6d9ae5_0  
plyfile                   0.6                       <pip>
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py27h1b593e1_0  
protobuf                  3.6.1                     <pip>
psutil                    5.4.3            py27h14c3975_0  
ptyprocess                0.5.2            py27h4ccb14c_0  
py                        1.5.2            py27h203d672_0  
PyAudio                   0.2.11                    <pip>
pycairo                   1.10.0                   py27_0  
pycodestyle               2.3.1            py27h904819d_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py27ha4109ae_0  
pycparser                 2.18             py27hefa08c5_1  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py27h14c3975_7  
pycurl                    7.19.0                   py27_0    anaconda
pyflakes                  1.6.0            py27h904a57d_0  
pygame                    1.9.4                     <pip>
pyglet                    1.3.2                     <pip>
pygments                  2.2.0            py27h4a8b6f5_0  
pylint                    1.8.2                    py27_0  
pymesh2                   0.2.0                     <pip>
pyodbc                    4.0.22           py27hf484d3e_0  
PyOpenGL                  3.1.0                     <pip>
pyopenssl                 17.5.0           py27hcee3be0_0  
pyOSC                     0.3.5b5294                <pip>
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py27hf1513f8_1  
pyqt                      5.6.0            py27h8210e8a_7    conda-forge
pyqtgraph                 0.10.0           py27h28b3542_3    anaconda
pysocks                   1.6.7            py27he2db6d2_1  
pytables                  3.4.4            py27h4f72b40_1    conda-forge
pytest                    3.3.2                    py27_0  
python                    2.7.11                        0  
python-dateutil           2.6.1            py27h4ca5741_1  
python-rtmidi             1.1.2                     <pip>
python-utils              2.3.0                     <pip>
python-xlib               0.23                      <pip>
pytorch                   0.4.1           py27__9.0.176_7.1.2_2    pytorch
pytz                      2017.3           py27h001bace_0  
pywavelets                0.5.2            py27hecda097_0  
pyxhook                   1.0.0                     <pip>
PyYAML                    3.13                      <pip>
pyyaml                    3.12             py27h2d70dd7_1  
pyzmq                     17.1.0                    <pip>
pyzmq                     16.0.3           py27hc579512_0  
qt                        5.6.2                         3    conda-forge
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py27hd7914c3_0  
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py27hc444b0d_0  
qtpy                      1.3.1            py27h63d3751_0  
readline                  6.2                           2  
requests                  2.19.1                    <pip>
requests                  2.18.4           py27hc5b0589_1  
resampy                   0.2.0                    py27_1    conda-forge
rope                      0.10.7           py27hfe459b0_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py27h14c3975_1  
scandir                   1.6              py27hf7388dc_0  
scikit-image              0.14.0           py27hf484d3e_1    anaconda
scikit-learn              0.20.0           py27h4989274_1  
scipy                     1.1.0                     <pip>
scipy                     1.1.0            py27hfa4b5c9_1  
seaborn                   0.8.1            py27h633ea1e_0  
send2trash                1.4.2                    py27_0  
setuptools                39.1.0                    <pip>
setuptools                38.4.0                   py27_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py27_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py27h9bcb476_0  
sip                       4.18                     py27_0  
six                       1.11.0           py27h5f960f1_1  
six                       1.11.0                    <pip>
sk-video                  1.1.10                    <pip>
smop                      0.41                      <pip>
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py27h44e2768_0  
sortedcollections         0.5.3            py27h135218e_0  
sortedcontainers          1.5.9                    py27_0  
sphinx                    1.6.6                    py27_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py27h1512b58_1  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py27hf906f22_1  
spyder                    3.2.6                    py27_0  
sqlalchemy                1.2.1            py27h14c3975_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        1    conda-forge
ssl_match_hostname        3.5.0.1          py27h4ec10b9_2  
statsmodels               0.8.0            py27hc87d62d_0  
subprocess32              3.2.7            py27h373dbce_0  
sympy                     1.1.1            py27hc28188a_0  
tblib                     1.3.2            py27h51fe5ba_0  
tensorboard               1.11.0                    <pip>
tensorflow-gpu            1.11.0                    <pip>
tensorflow-hub            0.1.1                     <pip>
tensorflowjs              0.6.1                     <pip>
termcolor                 1.1.0                     <pip>
terminado                 0.8.1                    py27_1  
testpath                  0.3.1            py27hc38d2c4_0  
tk                        8.5.19                        2    conda-forge
toolz                     0.9.0                    py27_0  
torchfile                 0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
torchfile                 0.1.0                     <pip>
torchvision               0.2.1                    py27_1    pytorch
tornado                   5.1                       <pip>
tornado                   4.5.3                    py27_0  
tqdm                      4.28.1           py27h28b3542_0    anaconda
traceback2                1.4.0                    py27_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2            py27hd6ce930_0  
typing                    3.6.2            py27h66f49e2_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py27h5062da9_0  
unittest2                 1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
unixodbc                  2.3.4                hc36303a_1  
urllib3                   1.22             py27ha55213b_0  
urllib3                   1.23                      <pip>
visdom                    0.1.8.4                   <pip>
vispy                     0.5.3                    py27_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py27h9e3e1ab_0  
webencodings              0.5.1            py27hff10b21_1  
websocket-client          0.48.0                    <pip>
websocket-client          0.48.0                     py_0    conda-forge
Werkzeug                  0.14.1                    <pip>
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py27_0  
wheel                     0.32.2                    <pip>
wheel                     0.30.0           py27h2bc6bb2_1  
wheel                     0.32.0                    <pip>
widgetsnbextension        3.1.0                    py27_0  
wrapt                     1.10.11          py27h04f6869_0  
x264                      20131218                      0    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.1.0            py27ha77178f_1  
xlsxwriter                1.0.2            py27h12cbc6b_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0            py27h3d85d97_0  
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7                h470a237_2    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.9                h470a237_4    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.2                h8c8a85c_6    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.6.6                h470a237_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.3                h470a237_4    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10               h470a237_2    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1               h470a237_2    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0                h470a237_2    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31               h470a237_7    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h470a237_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
yarg                      0.1.9                     <pip>
zeromq                    4.2.2                hbedb6e5_2  
zict                      0.1.3            py27h12c336c_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2  



$ conda config --show
add_anaconda_token: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
aggressive_update_packages:
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - openssl
allow_non_channel_urls: False
allow_softlinks: False
always_copy: False
always_softlink: False
always_yes: None
anaconda_upload: None
auto_update_conda: True
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: True
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
client_ssl_cert: None
client_ssl_cert_key: None
clobber: False
create_default_packages: []
custom_channels:
  pkgs/r: https://repo.anaconda.com
  home/memo/anaconda2/conda-bld: file://
  pkgs/main: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/free: https://repo.anaconda.com
custom_multichannels:
  local: ["file:///home/memo/anaconda2/conda-bld"]
  defaults: ["https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro"]
default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro
disallowed_packages: []
download_only: False
envs_dirs:
  - /home/memo/anaconda2/envs
  - /home/memo/.conda/envs
force: False
json: False
local_repodata_ttl: 1
max_shlvl: 2
migrated_channel_aliases: []
no_dependencies: False
non_admin_enabled: True
notify_outdated_conda: True
offline: False
override_channels_enabled: True
path_conflict: clobber
pinned_packages: []
pkgs_dirs:
  - /home/memo/anaconda2/pkgs
  - /home/memo/.conda/pkgs
proxy_servers: {}
quiet: False
remote_connect_timeout_secs: 9.15
remote_max_retries: 3
remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0
report_errors: None
rollback_enabled: True
safety_checks: warn
shortcuts: True
show_channel_urls: None
ssl_verify: True
track_features: []
use_index_cache: False
use_pip: True
verbosity: 0
whitelist_channels: []
```

Comment: But the first package it installs is `anaconda`. Maybe that is a huge collection package?

Comment: @Sraw No, the `anaconda` package is a so-called meta-package, which really means that it just has dependencies on all the actual packages. @memo what is the output of `conda config --list`?

Comment: @darthbith do you mean conda list? (conda config --list gives an error, config doesn't have that argument).  I just added that. It's huge, looks correct.

Comment: Sorry, the command is `conda config --show`. There's something strange about the channels for that new environment.

Comment: @darthbith ah ok, just added that, though I'm not sure what i'm looking at

Comment: Can you do `conda config --remove channels conda-forge` and try installing again?

Comment: @darthbith yes that did it thx! if you want to add that as an answer I will mark it as solved. (though it works, but I don't understand what exactly the problem is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that `conda-forge` appears first in the channel list. You can remove this channel with

```
conda config --remove channels conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1):

While removing Conda Forge from the global config will get around the particular issue, it could impact future solves on existing envs that had previously installed from Conda Forge. Instead, one can enforce the `anaconda` channel just for this particular env creation:

```
conda create -n py36 -c anaconda --override-channels python=3.6 anaconda
```